# Hide notification bar on Ubuntu phone (QML)

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml, notification-area

I would like to create and QML app with Ubuntu SDK for ubuntu phone.
I am not able to hide the notification bar at top of the screen.

What is the way to hide it ?
If it's not possible in QML only, HTML5 app have the same issue ?
If QML only and HTML5 app cannot hide this notification bar, how can I do it in C++ ?

Comment: It is outside of the app window even in plain C++ app with plain Qt/C++ widgets. So, i suppose, this will involve some interaction with Unity.

Comment: Hi Velkan, thanks for your comment. So how "PathWind" app (QML app) run in fullscreen mode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by putting your MainView in a QtQuick Window and setting `visibility: Window.Fullscreen` on that.  I'm not sure that this is the recommended solution, but it does seem to work.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1

Window {
    visibility: Window.FullScreen

    MainView {
        useDeprecatedToolbar: false
        anchors.fill: parent

        Page {
            title: "Fullscreen"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Robert Schroll, I don't know if it's the recommended solution too but it works. I will use it till a better way is defined. Thanks.